# Handler not catching autohorization and token mismatch exception. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I've been trying to handle the exception thrown by laravel since for a while. I've tried many things but it doesn't seems to be working. Following are my syntax i've used:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    //404 page when a model is not found
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }elseif ($e instanceof \AuthorizationException) {
        return response()->view('errors.403', [], 403);
    }elseif ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        Flash::error('Sorry, your session seems to have expired. Please try again.');
        return redirect('/');
    }elseif ($e instanceof \ErrorException) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }else {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }
    // return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

I've included followings:

```
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;
```

Further, following things were added previously:

```
protected $dontReport = [
    AuthorizationException::class,
    HttpException::class,
    ModelNotFoundException::class,
    ValidationException::class,
    TokenMismatchException::class,
];
```

Can anyone help me with this? I've stuck in this for days. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is that these exceptions are excluded by the framework and are therefore not reported. See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c14caab76aaffa6be2f227cd558cca096f0ea72f/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L56) for a reference.

As the property defining the excluded exceptions is `protected`, you should be able to override it in your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file. You should not remove all of these exceptions, but only the ones you really want to catch yourself. So simply add the following lines to your `Handler.php`:

```
/**
 * A list of the internal exception types that should not be reported.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $internalDontReport = [
    AuthenticationException::class,
    HttpException::class,
    HttpResponseException::class,
    ModelNotFoundException::class,
    ValidationException::class,
];
```

You will also have to add the `use` statements for all of the classes.

(Please be aware that this is the list of excluded exceptions for Laravel 5.6 - if you are using another version, you might have to use git blame or another branch to find the correct list for your version.)