# Laravel - logging "route not found"

Tags: laravel

I do not see any log output when a route is not found.  I am running laravel in development mode and I can see this error when hitting a route that does not exist.

```
"message": "",
"exception": 
"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
"file":
"/var/www/html/Customer_Interface/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
"line": 179,
```

However, it does not show any activity storage/logs.  Is there anyway to catch this exception and log it there?

Comment: I don't think this is a _direct_ answer, but something that I think  [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392184/laravel-5-7-how-to-log-404-with-url) would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel by default doesn't report these:

```php
//src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php

/**
     * A list of the internal exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $internalDontReport = [
        AuthenticationException::class,
        AuthorizationException::class,
        HttpException::class,
        HttpResponseException::class,
        ModelNotFoundException::class,
        SuspiciousOperationException::class,
        TokenMismatchException::class,
        ValidationException::class,
    ];
```

Now, you can in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` you can have that array imported then remove the `HttpException` and `ModelNotFoundException`, or whichever Exception you want like so

```php
    ...
    // app/Exceptions/Handler.php

    protected $internalDontReport = [
        AuthenticationException::class,
        AuthorizationException::class,
        // HttpException::class,
        HttpResponseException::class,
        // ModelNotFoundException::class,
        SuspiciousOperationException::class,
        TokenMismatchException::class,
        ValidationException::class,    
    ];
    ...
```

> `ModelNotFoundException` is when you have a route like `route::get('/articles/{article}','ArticleController@single');`
>
> and have that assigned in the controller as `function single(Article $article)` and `$article` is not found.

Pick what to keep and what to comment out.

### Second approach is to do this in the `report` method in the same `Handler.php` file

```php
 /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param \Exception $exception
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {

        # Report 404 
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException || $exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
             # Log as warning
             Log::warning('Your message');
             # Or Log as info
             Log::info($exception);
             // ...
        }
        ....
     }
```

You can find more about loggin in this [Laravel Logging](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/logging)
And [Laravel Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/errors)

Hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 1):

Within `Handler.php` (in directory Exceptions) there is an `$dontReport` array that holds the exception classes that shall not be reported. As far as I know the said NotFoundHttpException is listed there as default. If you remove it from the array the related exceptions should be represented in the logs.