# Laravel logs doesn't report some things

Tags: laravel, logging

I have an error, like the error below:
**Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.**
I know that's a error from routes, but I can't see anything in laravel.log.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268280/laravel-logging-route-not-found) I saw that Laravel doesn't report some things, but my Exceptions/Handler.php file is like this:

```
protected $dontReport = [
    //
];
```

How do I report everything in laravel.log?
Laravel 6

Comment: You can use the [log facade](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/logging) at the catch block of the request, logging the error as `Log::error($message);`.

Comment: But that way I need to make this in all request. What I would like is to see all the errors in logs

Comment: You can override the ```$internalDontReport ``` at the exception handler, as in the question you've cited [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268280/laravel-logging-route-not-found)

Comment: the framework itself has an internal list that it doesn't "report" which includes `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` which that exception extends from ... you would have to log this via your `report` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All exceptions are handled by the App\Exceptions\Handler class. Use the report method to log exceptions.

```
 public function report(Throwable $exception)
 {
    Log::error($exception); // add this line here
    parent::report($exception);
 }
```

See more from docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#report-method)